# Высококачественное масштабирование двумерных текстур

Tags: c++, windows, directx, 2d, текстура

Имеется экземпляр `ID3D11Texture2D`, который представляет текстуру содержащую некоторый текст небольшого размера. Задача состоит в уменьшении размера этой текстуры в 2 раза таким образом, чтобы текст сохранил читабельность.

**P.S.** Возможно использование сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Если вы используете `DirectX`, то почему бы не рендерить текст именно им?

Comment: Нет нет. Дана некоторая текстура с **уже нарисованным** текстом. Мы этот текст не знаем и распознавать, соответственно, тоже не должны :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67047/discussion-on-question-by-d-stark---).

Comment: Лет 10 назад Valve впервые задействовал Signed Distance Fields для отрисовки чёткого текста - метод работает в основном на увеличение и лишь с монохромным оригиналом. В то же время, он хорошо сохраняет чёткие контуры и при уменьшении. На английском SE есть [развитие](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/306/sharp-corners-with-signed-distance-fields-fonts) этой темы. Собственно, вопрос: насколько этот метод применим в вашей ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Хоть Вы и говорите, что распознавать текст не нужно, но кроме как найти этот текст на текстуре, сохранить его (в виде картинки), далее уменьшить текстуру и на неё наложить текст в оригинальном разрешении сложно придумать что - то более простое. Конечно даже такой вариант требует достаточно сложно алгоритма и будет работать только с простыми текстурами, вроде этой.

[image: оригинал]
[image: текст]

Не забудьте закрасить фон

[image: сжатая текстура]

проверить, что текст влезает в полученную текстуру, иначе уменьшить его

[image: сжатая текстура с текстом]

Comment: Соль в том, чтобы уменьшить сам текст.

Comment: В таком случае точно также всё сделать, но уменьшит текст, не уменьшая его разрешение

Answer (score 1):

Наилучший результат как при уменьшении, так и при увеличении дают *свёрточные фильтры*.

При их использовании уменьшение изображения очень похоже на наивное уменьшение, когда мы просто выбираем пиксели с определённым интервалом. Но чтобы не появилась некрасивая рябь, фильтр берёт не просто пиксели, а взвешенную сумму всех соседей на некотором расстоянии от этого пикселя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Матрица — это представление ядра свёртки в виде таблицы дискретных значений. В данном случае показан расчёт нового цвета для левого верхнего пикселя на основании цвета его непосредственных соседей.*

*<sup>Источник изображения: https://habrahabr.ru/post/142818/</sup>*

Для того, чтобы найти коэффициенты взвешенной суммы, воспользуемся *фильтром Ланцоша*. Он не даёт муара, а также повышает контраст изображения, делая границы чётче (что особо важно для относительно мелкого текста, читаемость которого необходимо сохранить).

*Мы бы могли вычислить эту таблицу самостоятельно (ради чего весь текст выше и затевался), но так как я немного запутался и в формулах, и в [GIMP-овом генераторе таблицы коэффициентов](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/gimp/2.6.1/scale-region_8c.html#aa45d148f4f263e46a3f1fdbdb1967710), предлагаю-таки воспользоваться готовой библиотекой.*

Соответственно, вам подойдёт любая библиотека, работающая с этим фильтром. Вот несколько примеров:

- [avir](https://github.com/avaneev/avir),
- [fpresize](https://github.com/jsummers/fpresize).

*Примечание: все эти библиотеки работают с изображением в оперативной, не видеопамяти. Соответственно применять их надо после загрузки из файла и перед отправкой в объект текстуры*.

Answer (score 1):

Переношу в ответ информацию из комментариев, для истории.

> Да в общем-то, в текущем виде, ответ на вопрос - "никак". Текстура
>   DirectX - обычное растровое изображение, уменьшение растрового
>   изображения в 2 раза означает потерю 50% информации. Для шрифта 10
>   размера при стандартном DPI это значит, что он будет нечитаем - тут
>   ничего не поделать. Но, более общая задача - представить информацию с
>   рабочего стола пользователя в таком виде, что ее можно отобразить в
>   любом масштабе, скорее всего решаема. Ведь текст в приложениях не
>   зарождается изначально в растровом виде, а выводится вызовом вполне
>   определенного набора функций из GDI, GDI+ и DirectWrite.

---

> Про механику DWM мало знаю. Но для текущей задачи он бесполезен, так
>   как оперирует теми же текстурами. Я намекаю на другое - замена на
>   целевой системе библиотек gdi и DirectWrite на свои взломанные версии,
>   которые бы логировали аргументы, передаваемые функциям вывода текста,
>   чтобы потом вызвать их с другим масштабом.